# Running Tux Typing in window

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, window

How can I run [Tux Typing](http://tux4kids.alioth.debian.org/tuxtype/download.php) on Ubuntu 15.04 in window mode? I've  dual screen and by default it runs on both screens, which makes it hard to use.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to `/home/yourusername/.tuxtype` in your file browser or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to view hidden files. You will find a file called `settings.txt` in this directory.
Open this file and find the line:

```
fullscreen=1
```

and change the `1` to  `0` to disable fullscreen mode. Save the file and close. Boot up the game and you will be running `tuxtype` in windowed mode!